# How to remove HTML Tags from String Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using Vue with Laravel. How can I remove HTML tags from content in Vue component

**Its like this**

```
<p> some content </p>
```

**I want it like this**

```
Some content
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `regEx` to remove html tags from string.. I think this example will help you, check the console in snippet

```js
var str = "<p> some content </p>";
console.log(str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ""));
```

Comment: It's really not recommended to try and parse HTML with regex.